# Objective-C properties on primitive data types

Tags: objective-c, properties

Having something like this

```
@interface MyClass : UIImageView {
   BOOL autoResize;
}
@property BOOL autoResize;
@end
```

I create an array of objects like this:

```
MyClass* o1 = [[MyClass alloc] init];
o1.autoResize = true;
[myArray addObject:o1];

MyClass* o2 = [[MyClass alloc] init];
o2.autoResize = false
[myArray addObject:o2];
```

The problem is the following: if I now use an iterator to iterate through all objects, myObject.autoResize allways(!) returns false. E.g:

```
for (MyClass elem in myArray) {
    elem.autoResize ? NSLog(@"true") : NSLog(@"false");
}
```

would echo "false", "false". I guess I have a vague why this happens (because BOOL is a primitive data type and not an object). But what is the best practice to deal with this issue?

Thanks

Christian

Comment: Mind showing more code, specifically MyClass implementation?

Comment: @CarlVeazey, there is no difference neither between the `YES` and `true` nor between the `NO` and `false`.

Comment: an asterisk `*` is missing from this line `for (MyClass *elem in myArray) {`

Comment: @holex: sorry, that was a type while copying the code to stackoverflow. It is correct in the source code.

Comment: @holex they are in fact different, look it up C99 bool types vs signed char & macro etc etc.

Comment: I can assure you your problem is not about primitive data types or boolean types.

Comment: have you synthesized `autoresize` in your MyClass.m ?

Comment: @CarlVeazey, you definitely missed to check the macro definitions of them. they are here for you: `#define true 1`, `#define false 0`, `#define YES (BOOL)1` and `#define NO (BOOL)0`, so please, tell me the difference, because I cannot see.

Comment: The issue isn't in the underlying values but in using the matching values for the types you declare. It's an issue of good style and writing code that fits in well with the platform. It's certainly not the cause of his issue but it's not correct to be assigning true and false to BOOL.

Comment: @holex http://db.tt/2XVv09RM here is the test I've made specially for you!

Comment: @holex I also made you a test on [github](https://github.com/paulsamuels/DotSyntaxProof) for your future reference.

Comment: okay guys, thank you, you are very kind. really. it seems you are more clever than me, so now, you should provide a solution for the asker, because wasting the time for the basics does not really helpful for this thread, am I right? ;)

Comment: @holex he figured out the problem himself and showed the importance of actually copying and pasting actual code as opposed to quickly rewriting it (and missing the important details). Also it's not about trying to be cleverer it's just about filling in the knowledge gaps of others and hoping someone else will help fill in mine.

Comment: **[Much Ado for Nothing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Much_Ado_About_Nothing)**...

Answer (score 1):

Try to add (nonatomic, assign) property modifiers

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL autoResize;
```

How it work you can read here: [Declared Properties](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProperties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH17-SW1)

Comment: @Prince there's nothing wrong with using assign for BOOL but nor is there any advantage to it that I can see - so I don't think the comment or the answer is right

Answer (score 0):

Sorry folks! That was a perfect example of why you should revisit your code before posting it here... Actually, what I did was:

```
MyClass* o1 = [[MyClass alloc] init];
o1.autoResize = true;
[myArray addObject:o1];

myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];  // OMG! What is this doing here :-(

MyClass* o2 = [[MyClass alloc] init];
o2.autoResize = false
[myArray addObject:o2];
```

As I had dozends of objects I simply overlooked this line... Thanks @Carl Veazey for the hint.

bye
     Christian

Comment: d'oh! glad you figured it out :)